# If it rains on succot what does it signify

Tags: sukkot, weather

If it rains on succot meaning one cannot eat in the succah and must therefore stay in the house. Is this 'rain' just coincidence, or is hashem telling you 'I dont want you to keep my mizvot' perhaps because you dont deserve them in your present state and are not 'up' to them?

If the latter, what are other similar mitsvot where whilst doing them, hashem in a sense 'throws' them back 'in your face' and says 'I dont want them from you' and I would rather you would not do them?

Comment: I don't know about you, but the vast majority of the rain I have ever experienced in a sukkah was very clearly God saying, "Make Aliyah already!'

Comment: I don't know about you, but when it rains in my sukkah, it's G-d giving me an opportunity to practice iskafia/mesiras nefesh by staying outside.

Comment: ...or what the Gemara would call "hedyotus". But hey, if being a [English word somewhere between "uneducated simpleton" and "idiot"] makes you feel good, then i suppose it's Simchas Yom Tov?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm perfectly happy to be a hedyot together with the [Baal Shem Tov et al.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10486/883) Incidentally, if this were a riddle, the parable in that answer might also be applicable here.

Comment: @Hod No need to worry. There are thousands upon thousands of Hedyotos you are joining from over the last four thousand years, each with their own personal reasons for being so. So if you were worried you would be alone, I can assure you you'll have a most varied crowd. (Proportionally, it's probably an excellent place to start doing some Kiruv and setting up Tefillin booths!)

Comment: @DoubleAA Tefillin on Sukkos? ;). Also, given OP's answer, I'm pretty sure this is either a riddle or a [clothesline for my cute vort](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/how-to-handle-clothesline-for-my-cute-vort-questions).

Comment: @DoubleAA But.... the rainy season in Israel starts on Sukkot...

Comment: @Charles So it is theoretically possible but still quite unlikely. Exactly the set of odds I'd like to see for this

Comment: @HodofHod Hey, if you sit in the Sukkah in the rain, you might as well put tefillin on on chol hamoed. At least in the latter case some rishonim think you are doing something of halachik value.

Comment: @DoubleAA So why not [Macapá, Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macap%C3%A1#Climate) :)

Comment: This question appears to be a riddle and/or a non-realistic question that would not be asked unless you had the answer already in hand. These types of questions are usually discouraged or disallowed on this site. For more information, see these meta discussions: [Clothesline for my cute vort](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1081/), [riddles](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140/883), and [self-answers](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/307/883).

Comment: @SethJ Oh, it was definitely asked as a riddle - OP's answer makes that clear. The question is whether it's closeable as one. I think it is.

Comment: @HodofHod, oh, I didn't see the answer given. Thanks. I retract my comment (although I can't retract my close vote to change the reason).

Comment: (@HodofHod, I still think it's *also* unclear.)

Comment: @SethJ Oh, absolutely. I think that the OP made it that way intentionally. His answer says things like _"...if someone at last can find out what I am talking about. I have almost said it."_ That said, I think even if it were clearer it would still be a clothesline.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the shifting Hebrew calendar, plus that you are likely living in the US, I would say that it is not a negative omen, as intended by Chazal. I will cite [my blogpost](http://parsha.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/is-rain-negative-omen-on-succot.html) about this.

> Succot, in the time of the Mishna, was right before the rainy season. It was possible for rain to come then, but not as likely. But then, the Hebrew calendar was fixed, and there is seasonal drift of this lunar calendar compared with the solar calendar. To cite [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) on this:
>
> The seriousness of the spring equinox drift is widely discounted on the grounds that Passover will remain in the spring season for many millennia, and the text of the Torah is generally not interpreted as having specified tight calendrical limits. On the other hand, the mean southward equinoctial year length is considerably shorter, so the Hebrew calendar has been drifting faster with respect to the autumn equinox, and at least part of the harvest festival of Sukkot is already more than a month after the equinox in years 1, 9, and 12 of each 19-year cycle; beginning in Hebrew year 5818 (2057 CE), this will also be the case in year 4. (These are the same year numbers as were mentioned for the spring season in the previous paragraph, except that they get incremented at Rosh Hashanah.) This progressively increases the probability that Sukkot will be cold and wet, making it uncomfortable or impractical to dwell in the traditional succah during Sukkot. The first winter seasonal prayer for rain is not recited until Shemini Atzeret, after the end of Sukkot, yet it is becoming increasingly likely that the rainy season in Israel will start before the end of Sukkot.
>
> End quote from Wikipedia.
>
> Once mashiach comes and we reestablish the calendar according to moon sighting, bet din could simply make one leap year NOT a leap year, and we would be more or less back on track. But as it stands, as the years progress, it becomes more and more likely that it rains on succot. Nishtaneh hateva. This is derech hateva, and not necessarily a sign of Divine displeasure.

Comment: Though it should remind us if we do live somewhere like Seattle, that the Mitzvot were meant to be kept in Israel and this place is just a temporary stop before moving there.

Answer (score -6):

No one seems to have answered the question. Perhaps because the answer is so well known. It is an example of a king asking his servant to prepare wine (by mixing with water) and then spilling the water (over him). This tells the servant that he doesnt want his 'services'. Hashem is also telling us by bringing rain that he doesnt want our mitsvot and would rather do without them. Meaning we are not on the madrega to be able to do them and please him.

This goes against the lubavich (and other kiruv) principles to get people to do mitvot. Hashem doesnt want 'everyone's' mitvot only from 'certain' people who are on  the madrega.

This question was only put here because of its supplementary which cannot be answered elsewhere at the moment. This has so far not produced any answers and seems to have eluded everyone here. It is quite a long answer having to explain a difficult gemoro with many shittos, some totally against the gemoro and I will do so slowly.

I will first add a chiddush of my own which will go someway to explaining the 'rain'.

The moshol or parable is of a king and his servant. He most likely only had one servant (at a time) who mixed his drinks. Providing a 'downpour' seems like collective 'punishment' or displeasure. It doesnt usually rain just on one succah and not on the next. And also in the other examples of this kind of thing, of hashem expressing his displeasure it is not in a  'collective' way but a private one.

I therefore think although highly unusual and  improbable but still possible, that it really refers to when it rained on one succah and not on the next. There are such chasidic tales. That is clear proof that hashem is not interested in your mitsvot.

Although the example I gave on another thread was regarding a person who is not yet ready to learn kabala and does so, the gemoro refers to another example and the poskim like the chayai odom say it refers to that as well.

In the gemoro's example where the early poskim give the same moshol of the king and servant, matters are more serious. There it is a 'private' and 'deadly' sign not a collective one like with rain and although the mishne berura and others tells you what to do about it, basically to learn, daven certain tfillos daily, and good deeds, there is still some arguement if it will save you from death or just make your passage to the next world 'easier'.

To be continued if found to be of interest or if someone at last can find out what I am talking about. I have almost said it.

Comment: there is a bit more to the moshol than you summarize http://www.vbm-torah.org/talmud10/20.htm

Comment: That site doesnt seem to be aware that this moshol is also used for other mitvot not just rain on a succah.

Comment: The site mentioned that: "The difference is that according to the hava amina, the rain is the water that we are symbolically spilling on God via our inadequate performance of mitzvot." Mitzvot, in the plural and general. Not just sukkah.

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment. I agree that this is so that hashem isnt angry just for the non performance of succah but all other mitsvot.

Comment: When I said this moshol is used for other mitsvot I meant like my posts says that hashem shows his 'displeasure' in other mitstvot but not through 'rain' when also  performing other mitsvot not just succah.

Comment: actually the nimshal is, according to one opinion, that hashem is unhappy with inadequate performance, not just with performance. There are many different understandings of the meaning of the moshol presented on that page. Your choice of one reading shouldn't ignore that others see the message differently.

Comment: "hashem doesn't want insincere or improperly performed (inadequate) mitzvot" is different from "hashem doesn't want performance of mitzvot" and the page provides a number of different nimshals and interpretations deciphering what the various pieces stand for and what the message is